# Code to find top 95 percent of column values in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am looking for help gathering the top 95 percent of sales in a Pandas Data frame where I need to group by a category column.  I found the following (top section of code) which is close.  `TotalDollars` in my df gets properly sorted in descending fashion, but the resulting number of rows includes more than top 95% of total dollars.

```
Total Dollars     Percent     Running Percent

117388     11.09%    11.09%

81632     7.71%     18.80%

46316     4.38%     23.18%

41500     3.92%     27.10%
```

after hitting 95% running total percent want to eliminate remaining rows for that category.  I don't need Percent or Running Percent as df fields (given for illustrative purposes only).

```
df1 = (df.groupby('channel',group_keys=False)
        .apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(int(len(x) * a), 'score')))
```

my code:

```
df_out = (df_Sales.groupby('category', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(int(len(x) * 0.95), 'TotalDollars')))
```

Comment: maybe `quantile` can help? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.quantile.html?highlight=percentile. Then you will need another step to apply masks on values greater than the quantile

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


np.random.seed(100)

test_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': ['A'] * 5 + ['B'] * 5,
    'value': np.random.randint(1,100,10)
})


def retain_quantile(df, percentile=0.95):
    percentile_val = df['value'].quantile(percentile)

    return df[df['value'] <= percentile_val]

grouped_df = test_df.groupby('group').apply(retain_quantile)
grouped_df

        group  value
group
A     0     A      9
      1     A     25
      2     A     68
      4     A     80
B     5     B     49
      6     B     11
      7     B     95
      8     B     53
```

if you're planning on using this for multiple columns, it would be a lot more complicated but the approach is very similar.

Comment: When I tried the above code it removed 14 lines from a set of 280 which is 95%.  However, what I am aiming for is a method to keep only the lines where the cumulative TotalSales figures largest to smallest is 95% of all total sales.  In performing the task via excel manually the number of records actually encompasses 164 records.  Other ideas?